# How can I analyse which collections get the most reads?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting an unusually high amount of reads on my Firebase app and I would like to know precisely where they occur. For example, in which collection, in which document in a collection. If it is a listener that's adding up reads or simple reads.

Answer (score 1):

There are currently no tools to audit Firestore access.  You will have to log access from your application code and collect those somewhere for you to analyze.

Realtime updates from the Firestore console is often a source of [unexpected reads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56434008/firestore-unexpected-reads).