# Why Cloud Firestore updates so much?

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a project for a logistics warehouse.
The idea is that I use Cloud Firestore for store pallets in a rack and that I can find it back in the system.

I can see my pallets in the app and it works well.
Cloud Firestore has a read amount of 50.000 reads per day.
If I start up the app it calculates the number of documents in the list and I can see it in the usage tab.
That's okay but even if I do nothing in the app, the number increases.

Is there a solution to read the data only if the flutter page opens?

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class overzicht extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _overzichtState createState() => _overzichtState();
}

class _overzichtState extends State<overzicht> {
  Future _data;
  Future getPosts() async{

    var firestore = Firestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection("locaties").getDocuments();
    return qn.documents;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _data = getPosts();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Center(child: Text('Overzicht')),backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(17, 32, 42, 1),),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _data,
            builder: (_, snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
            return Center(
              child: Text('Loading...'),
              );
          } else{
           return ListView.builder(
               itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
               itemBuilder: (_, index){
                 return ListTile(
                   title: Text(snapshot.data[index].data["location"]),
                 );
           });
          }
        }),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: Sure, you can choose when to run your queries. It's not really clear to me where you are stuck with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56434555/5495197):

> If you leave the console open on a collection/document with busy write activity, the console will automatically read the changes that update the console's display.  This is very often the source of unexpected reads.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it. 