# Firebase read document count using flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How many read in firebase if under one await I run a loop and I have 20 documents in total but my loop will filter out some after checking. After checking it will take 10 data. But for taking, it needs to read 20 documents. So how many read will it count? I heard one await one read. But my firebase dashboard is showing 5/6 times more. In the picture i have shown the code.
**please tell me how many read will it count?**

```
  Future getUser() async {
    final id = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    userId=id.uid;
    await Firestore.instance.collection('user').getDocuments().then((users) {
      print("loop running");
      for (var user in users.documents) {
        if ((!seenList1.contains(user.documentID)) &&
            (!chosenList1.contains(user.documentID)) &&
            (!showId1.contains(user.documentID)) &&
            (user.documentID != userId) &&
            ("male" == user['gender'])

        ) {


          loc(user['Location'].latitude, user['Location'].longitude).then((result){
            if(result==true){
              setState(() {

                showId1.add(user.documentID)  ;
                showName1.add(user['name']) ;   }

          });

        }
      }
    });
    return ;
  }
```

Comment: If you are trying to figure out how many reads are happening in your code, you should close the Firebase console, since it costs reads to view documents.  See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56434555

Comment: Please share the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `getDocuments()` determines how many documents are read. So in your case:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('user').getDocuments()
```

This means that all documents from the `user` collection are read. If those documents are not in the local cache of the device yet, Firestore will have to read them on the server and return them to the client.

So say your cache is empty: that'd mean that you're charged a read for each document in the `user` collection, and the total bandwidth that is used for downloading those documents.

Comment: I know getDocuments() will read all documents but my question is how many read will it charge. I am just checking those data's  for filtering

Comment: You are charged for each document that is read from the server. What you do with it in your code doesn't matter: as soon as the document is retrieved (in your code by `getDocuments()`) you are charged for it.