# Extremely high READ hits on website using Firebase Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, snapshot

I have more than 52k hits on my small project which is using NextJS with Firebase 9.

I don't know what the problem is because the data I am using is very limited and I have only two snapshot listener and one Authentication feature. But somehow in just two days Firestore quota has exceeded and there are more than 52k READ hits.

I don't know why that happened because there are no memory leaks and I am also closing the API listeners which come attached with Firebase.

I am providing github link in case anyone wants to take a look https://github.com/jainChetan81/Todo-List

Attached screenshot of Firebase console:
[image: firebse console screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use of the Firebase console will incur reads. If you leave the console open on a collection or document with busy write activity then the Firebase console will automatically read the changes that update the console's display. Most of the time this is the reason for unexpected high reads. You can go through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56434555). Also, currently there are no tools to trace the reads in Firestore. So to limit the Firestore database reads you have to configure security rules.

So, I would suggest you check your Firestore rules. And if not, it is better to contact [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support) as this kind of issue needs visibility into your project and they will have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem as you with my React app. The solution is to use the `useEffect` hook and call the function that requests for firestore collection;

```
useEffect(()=> {
  getPosts();
}, []);
```