# How to get insights on which collection is having the most Read operations on Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to figure out how can I analyze, which collection on my Firestore has the most Read operations.

So far I can't seem to find anything, even on Google Cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way in which you can know which Firestore collection is most accessed. You can, however, log all accesses in your application code and collect the numbers so you can further analyze them.

In my experience, one of the most known common sources of unexpected reads is the Firebase Console. The console is considered a client like any other web or mobile client. Here are some info:

- [Firestore - unexpected reads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56434008/firestore-unexpected-reads)